# Trying to add to the end of a linked list in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am working on a homework assignment where I need to make a linked list in ruby.  In particular at this juncture I am having a hard time setting a new node to the end of the list.

Right now I keep trying to use the method `@tail.next` to try and go down the list of nodes to find the one with a value of `nul`, (because that is the last one)

the only problem is when it goes through the first time I get an Rspec failure of `undefined method "next" for nil:NilClass`

**EDIT** this was the winning method that fixed my `add_to_tail` function.

```
 def add_to_tail(node)
    if(@next)
       @tail.next = node
    else
      @tail= node
    end 
  end
```

this is the `node.rb`file

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :next
  attr_accessor :data

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
    #@next = nil
  end
end
```

this is the `linked_list.rb` file

```
require_relative 'node'

class LinkedList
  attr_accessor :head
  attr_accessor :tail

#I want this method to check if @tail.next has a node value or is nil
#If @tail.next is nil I want to assign the node value being passed in

  def add_to_tail(node)   
 # This method creates a new `Node` using `data`, and inserts it at the end of the list.

#I want this method to check if @tail.next has a node value or is nil
#If @tail.next is nil I want to assign the node value being passed in
    if @tail.next != nil
      @tail.next = node
    else
      @tail.next = nil
    end
end
```

this is the Rspec test I am trying to pass...

```
include RSpec

require_relative 'node'
require_relative 'linked_list'

RSpec.describe LinkedList, type: Class do
  let(:n1) { Node.new("Rob") }
  let(:n2) { Node.new("Ben") }
  let(:n3) { Node.new("Mike") }
  let(:llist) { LinkedList.new }

  describe "#add_to_tail" do
    it "adds a Node to the tail" do
      llist.add_to_tail(n1)
      expect(llist.tail).to eq n1
      llist.add_to_tail(n2)
      expect(llist.tail).to eq n2
    end
  end
```

Comment: One thing to remember when working with Ruby is very few things are logically false, only `nil` and `false` qualify. This means most of the time code can be written as `@tail.next` not `@tail.next != nil`. The only exception is if you ever need to distinguish between `nil` and `false`, as in "not assigned" versus "deliberately set to false". This also avoids a double-negative, the `else` clause there is equivalent to *if `tail.next` is not not equal to `nil`*. You may find `@tail.next ||= node` does the job anyway.

Comment: Be sure to use `next` carefully as it is reserved keyword and you might end up getting unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this either recursively:

```
class Node
  def append(node)
    if (@next)
      @next.append(node)
    else
      @next = node
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can simply iterate:

```
def add_to_tail(node)
  tail = @tail

  while (@tail.next)
    tail = tail.next
  end

  tail.next = node
end
```

You'll probably want to approach solving this problem by using simple unit tests to exercise your code and be sure it works as expected. For example, the [`test/unit`](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit) gem or [RSpec](http://rspec.info) if you like more behavioural models.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am still a bit new and don't COMPLETELY understand everything I just did but was able to get it working with just some minor tweaks.